# Centrally managing or updating the content types of all document libraries in SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, content-type, managed-metadata

So I have read articles on Managed Metadata, Content Type Publishing and Editing Document Library templates and while related none of these seem to do what I want to do.  I want to add the "Link to Document" content type to all existing document libraries in a site collection.  At that point I can edit the document library template so that I never have to do it again.  Is this possible?  If there isn't a built in way to do it is there a way to do it in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PowerShell.  A simple bing search returned this....
http://thesharepointproject.com/2012/05/18/adding-content-types-using-powershell-content-types-part-1/